# VBA Copying a Range and pasting to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range from a cell to the end of another cell in the same row.
I have the following code in an if loop.

```
Sheet2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, c)).Copy
Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Paste
```

Sheet2 and Sheet 3 are structured in the same way thus I'm using the same variables for the row.

On top of that, how do I paste cells to the next empty cell of that particular row of the loop?

Comment: Are you having problems copying and pasting? If so what error at you getting at what line.

Comment: It will run into this error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace with the below:

```
Dim rn As Range, rn1 As Range, sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet


Set sh = Sheet2
Set sh1 = Sheet3

With sh

Set rn = .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, c))
Set rn1 = sh1.Cells(i, 2)


rn.Copy rn1

End With
```

if c it is not a variable please replace with "c"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sheet2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, c)).Copy destination:=Sheet3.Cells(i, 2)
```

If you do it in 2 steps, you might need to `.Resize` the target range in order to match the size of the source range.

Comment: Hi I tried your code, but it will run into this error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"